# Backbone router.route isn't setting route

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following router defined, but the `.route` function doesn't seem to be setting.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks, in advance, for the help.

```
# app.js.coffee

initialize: =>
  router = new Backbone.Router
  router.route "foo/:bar", "baz"
  console.log router.routes # returns undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routes you create using `Router.route` are stored internally in the `History` object -- they're not added to the `Router.routes` collection.

They still work though, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FMhZL/3/) for proof.  Note that in `this.routes`, only the `home` route is defined, but you're still able to hit the `baz` route.  You *can* see the `baz` route if you check `Backbone.history.handlers`, which is where the routes are actually stored.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.route("foo/:bar", "baz");
    },
    routes: {
        "": "home"  
    },
    home: function() {
        console.log("home hit");
    },
    baz: function(bar) {
        console.log('test hit: ' + bar);
    },
});
var router = new Router();
console.log(this.routes);
console.log(Backbone.history.handlers);
Backbone.history.start();
router.navigate("foo/testbar", { trigger: true });
```

---

​

Note though, I think you need to use `this` in your code, because `router` won't be defined yet inside `initialize`:

```
@route "foo/:bar", "baz"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, dbaseman. You're right about their internal storage - I was unclear about that.  To be more specific, though, for future viewers, it appears they're stored in the Backbone.history object in the handlers property.  Good to know!

Comment: @mlp.brooklyn yes, good catch about Backbone.history.  I've fixed that part of my answer.